# Query For Navigating Views In C# with Avalonia UI

Tags: c#, view, navigation, avaloniaui, avalonia

So, I've just started a C# project testing out Avalonia UI, I am working on a basic menu navigation system and I'm running into a problem of my navigation system not switching correctly, rather than switching the views it's just displaying a string of the view location.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMQqb.png)

This is my MainWindowViewModel.cs code:

```
using AvaloniaApplication.ViewModels;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace AvaloniaApplication.ViewModels;

public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
#pragma warning disable CA1822 // Mark members as static

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ViewModelBase _currentPage = new HomePageViewModel();

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ListItemTemplate? _selectedListItem;

    partial void OnSelectedListItemChanged(ListItemTemplate? value)
    {
        if (value is null) return;
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(value.ModelType);
        if (instance is null) return;
        CurrentPage = (ViewModelBase)instance;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ListItemTemplate> Items { get; } = new()
    {
        new ListItemTemplate(typeof(HomePageViewModel)),
        new ListItemTemplate(typeof(RosterViewModel))
    };

}

public class ListItemTemplate
{
public ListItemTemplate(Type type)
{
    ModelType = type;
    Label = type.Name.Replace("PageViewModel", "");
}

public string Label { get; }
public Type ModelType { get; }
}
```

This is my MainWindow.axaml

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:AvaloniaApplication.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="AvaloniaApplication.Views.MainWindow"
        x:DataType="vm:MainWindowViewModel"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="AvaloniaApplication">

    <Design.DataContext>
        <!-- This only sets the DataContext for the previewer in an IDE,
             to set the actual DataContext for runtime, set the DataContext property in code (look at App.axaml.cs) -->
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Design.DataContext>

  <SplitView IsPaneOpen="True"
             OpenPaneLength="100"
             Background="White"
             PaneBackground="Purple">
    <SplitView.Pane>

      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListItem}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ListItemTemplate}">
            <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ListBox>
   

    </SplitView.Pane>

    <SplitView.Content>
      <TransitioningContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
      
    </SplitView.Content>
  </SplitView>

</Window>
```

If anyone has any suggestions of where I am likely going wrong I would appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: I have somewhat the same question, i'm currently getting stuck in the [ToDo-List-Tutorial](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/tutorials/todo-list-app/navigate-views) at the step to navigate views, i also just get the .ToString representation of the ViewModelBase when having a more or less similiar code as you do.
Seems like in the past they were using a ViewLocator, like shorty described in their documentation ["How to implement Multi-page Apps"](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/guides/development-guides/how-to-implement-multi-page-apps), but that is not created in new projects as it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I looked that up because i had more or less the same problems, but regarding the ToDo-List-Tutorial at step [Navigate Views](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/tutorials/todo-list-app/navigate-views).

I got it working using a ViewLocator, the one from the [documentation](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/concepts/view-locator) and followed the guide in there on how to make sure it's used.

Basicly copy the class of the documentation and add the following to the *App.axaml*:

a definition of local to the application tag attributes (see **xmlns:local**) and the locator as a **DataTemplate** so that your *App.axaml* might look like this:

```
<Application xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="using:AvaloniaTodoList.ViewModels"
             x:Class="AvaloniaTodoList.App"
             xmlns:local="using:AvaloniaTodoList"
             RequestedThemeVariant="Default">
  <!-- "Default" ThemeVariant follows system theme variant. "Dark" or "Light" are other available options. -->

  <Application.DataTemplates>
    <local:ViewLocator />
  </Application.DataTemplates>

  <Application.Styles>
    <FluentTheme />
  </Application.Styles>
</Application>
```

And if (in my case) the MainWindowViewModel now has a ViewModelBase as Property like so:

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
 {
     private ViewModelBase _contentViewModel;

     //this has a dependency on the ToDoListService

     public MainWindowViewModel()
     {
         var service = new ToDoListService();
         ToDoList = new ToDoListViewModel(service.GetItems());
         _contentViewModel = ToDoList;
     }

     public ToDoListViewModel ToDoList { get; }

     public ViewModelBase ContentViewModel
     {
         get => _contentViewModel;
         private set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _contentViewModel, value);
     }

     public void AddItem()
     {
         ContentViewModel = new AddItemViewModel();
     }
 }
```

now the Content can be set to that in the *MainWindow.axaml* using the **DataType** and **Content** attribute :

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:AvaloniaTodoList.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:AvaloniaTodoList.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        Width="250"
        Height="450"
        x:Class="AvaloniaTodoList.Views.MainWindow"
        x:DataType="vm:MainWindowViewModel"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="Avalonia Todo List"
        Content="{Binding ContentViewModel}">  
        <!--<views:ToDoListView/>-->
</Window>
```

May something similiar helps in your case?